# Не обновляется состояние Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Использую 'react-fileupload' для выбора файла и отправки на сервер, в случае успеха получаю ответ с содержимым файла, но состояние хранилища не обновляется.

Компонент с загрузчиком:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FileUpload from 'react-fileupload';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { updateOverview } from '../actions/index';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    const options = {
      baseUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload_file',
      chooseAndUpload: true,
      uploadSuccess: function(res) {
        console.log('success');
        updateOverview(res.data);
      },
      uploadError: function(err) {
        alert(err.message);
      }
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <FileUpload options={options} ref="fileUpload">
          <button
            className="yellow darken-2 white-text btn-flat"
            ref="chooseAndUpload">
            Upload
          </button>
        </FileUpload>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ updateOverview }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

Компонент, где отображается содержимое файла:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Overview extends Component {
  renderContent() {
    console.log(this.props.overview);
    if (!this.props.overview) {
      return <div> Upload file!</div>;
    }
    return this.props.overview;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Overview</h1>
        {this.renderContent()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps({ overview }) {
  return { overview };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Overview);
```

Action creator:

```js
import { FETCH_OVERVIEW } from './types';

export function updateOverview(data) {
  return { type: FETCH_OVERVIEW, payload: data };
}
```

reducer index.js

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import overviewReducer from './overviewReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  overview: overviewReducer
});
```

overviewReducer.js

```js
import { FETCH_OVERVIEW } from '../actions/types';
export default function(state = null, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_OVERVIEW:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: значит у вас диспатчер не выстреливает, вот и все

Comment: А почему он не выстреливает?

Comment: Исходный код в гит дадите?

Comment: А как он будет выстреливать, если в `uploadSuccess`, `updateOverview` просто выкидывает впустую `{ type: FETCH_OVERVIEW, payload: data }`, а должен передавать это дело в диспатчер?